# Validate XML and DTD in browser

Tags: html, xml, dtd

I have to make a validation of my XML and DTD, my question is what would happen if I remove my XML tag that is defined as a required field in the DTD?, It will continue displaying the XML in the browser?, Or mark me an error? , Or in his case as validate such situations?.

Annex I DTD and XML

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE Dispositivos SYSTEM "productosDTD.dtd">
> <Dispositivos>
>     <Dispositivo  id="kos1000" nombreProducto="Cafetera" marca="Oster" precio="275 MXN">
>         <fechaImportacion> 05/04/1992</fechaImportacion>
>         <precioAduana>85</precioAduana>
>         <idPedido>Mtg08042013</idPedido>
>         <nombreAduana>Viva Mexico</nombreAduana>
>         <observacionesProducto> Excelente Estado :D </observacionesProducto> 
>     <fabricanteDispositivo nombre="La Rivera" calle="Av de las Granjas"
>      numero="1230" delegacion="Azcapotzalco" entidadFederativa="DF" 
>      codigoPostal="02230" />
>     </Dispositivo>
> </Dispositivos>
> ```

And productosDTD.dtd

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!--
> To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
> and open the template in the editor.
> -->
>
> <!--
>     TODO define vocabulary identification data
>     PUBLIC ID  : -//vendor//vocabulary//EN
>     SYSTEM ID  : http://server/path/__NAME__
> -->
>
> <!-- TODO define your own vocabulary/syntax. Example follows:  -->
> <!ELEMENT Dispositivos (Dispositivo*)>
> <!ELEMENT Dispositivo (fechaImportacion,precioAduana,idPedido,nombreAduana,
>           observacionesProducto,fabricanteDispositivo)>
> <!ATTLIST Dispositivo  
>  id  CDATA #REQUIRED
>  nombreProducto CDATA #REQUIRED
>  marca CDATA #REQUIRED
>  precio CDATA #REQUIRED
> >
>
> <!ELEMENT fechaImportacion (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT precioAduana (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT nombreAduana (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT  observacionesAduana (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT  observacionesProducto (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT idPedido (#PCDATA)>
> <!ELEMENT fabricanteDispositivo (#PCDATA)>
> <!ATTLIST fabricanteDispositivo 
>  nombre CDATA #REQUIRED
> calle CDATA #REQUIRED
> numero CDATA #REQUIRED
> delegacion CDATA #REQUIRED
> entidadFederativa  CDATA #REQUIRED
> codigoPostal CDATA #REQUIRED
> >
> ```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Which browser are you referring to, and how does the title of the question relate to the question itself? Besides, why would you remove your XML tag (whatever tag that might be)?

Comment: I have to do tests to validate the following situation:
What happens if I remove a label such as name and street fabricanteDispositivo which is data that are defined in the DTD as mandatory data, my question is how to validate this situation, I make some mistake?, I'm in IE, say there is a plugin "Tools XML Validation "but can not find".

Answer (score 0):

To validate a XML file you need a validator. I'm not sure if some is included in a browser. If not then the XML will be shown without attention of the validity.

By the way I would prefer XML Schema for the validation of a XML file. You also need a validator but you can configure it more exactly.